# ImportError: Failed to load PyTorch C extensions

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a problem with importing torch into my project, when I try to import it I get the following error:

```
ImportError: Failed to load PyTorch C extensions:
     It appears that PyTorch has loaded the `torch/_C` folder
     of the PyTorch repository rather than the C extensions which
     are expected in the `torch._C` namespace. This can occur when
     using the `install` workflow. e.g.
         $ python setup.py install && python -c "import torch"

     This error can generally be solved using the `develop` workflow
         $ python setup.py develop && python -c "import torch" # This should succeed
     or by running Python from a different directory.

Not only with importing torch into your project but also with other libraries using it as a dependency.
```

Python 3.10.10

Torch 2.0.0

I tried reinstalling torch but it didn't work, I can't figure out what the problem is, can you help me?

Comment: This is happening for me with Torch 2.0.1 and Python 3.9 (environment in a conda install) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure torch is installed with latest python. I used python 3.11 and worked for me. I got error because I installed torch with python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

For me the

```
pip uninstall torch
pip install torch
```

worked, because originally I had the torch version 2.2.1+cu121 which means it tried to run of CUDA. After reinstalling pytorch I had the version 2.2.1 without CUDA, and my ml-agents finally work.

Maybe CUDA will need a reinstallation/update as well to work with ml-agents.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall torch

```
pip uninstall torch
pip install torch
```